# No URLMap entries found in application configuration

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a node.js application to Google App Engine Standard as per the instructions available on the following link
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart

When I deploy I get the following error

```
C:\Code\NodeJS\nodejs-docs-samples\appengine\hello-world\standard (master)
λ gcloud app deploy
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [C:\Code\NodeJS\nodejs-docs-samples\appengine\hello-world\standard\app.yaml]
No URLMap entries found in application configuration
  in "C:\Code\NodeJS\nodejs-docs-samples\appengine\hello-world\standard\app.yaml", line 17, column 1
```

The app.yaml file contents are as follows:

```
# Copyright 2017, Google, Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs8
# [END app_yaml]
```

~

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the flexible environment in which your app itself is responsible for mapping request URLs to handlers, in the standard environment this is something that needs to be configured in the `app.yaml` file, so that GAE is aware of such mapping. From [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element) (go through the entire table in that section, new in the standard environment):

> The `handlers` element provides a list of URL patterns and
>   descriptions of how they should be handled. App Engine can handle URLs
>   by executing application code, or by serving static files uploaded
>   with the code, such as images, CSS, or JavaScript.
>
> Patterns are evaluated in the order they appear in the `app.yaml`
>   file, from top to bottom. The first mapping whose pattern matches the
>   URL is the one used to handle the request.

All you need to do is provide at least one such URL handler mapping for your app.

Comment: The GAE samples for Nodejs don't seem to include any handlers elements, it just seems to route straight to the app, which I think would make sense unless GAE also proscribed a specific web framework. I found upgrading using `gcloud components update` got rid of this error for me (although I'm still working on a different error) https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/hello-world/standard/app.yaml

Comment: @RichardMarr Well, possible, but the documentation doesn't appear to be covering that. The NodeJS support seem to be a bit different in this respect compared to the other standard env sandboxes. Anyways, you still need to provide the handling code inside your app, even if it doesn't actually need a mapping in the `app.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

[Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842007/no-urlmap-entries-found-in-application-configuration/50842459#50842459) got me on the right track.

For posterity's sake, here's an example app.yaml file to resolve that error message:

```
runtime: nodejs8
handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```